# Setting color for define-constants in vim

Tags: vim

Imagine I have that line:

```
#define CONST 10
```

I would like a «CONST» word to be red everywhere further in my code, but I have no idea how to implement that. I tried this approach:

```
:hi Comment term=bold ctermfg=Red guifg=#80a0ff gui=bold
```

but it changes the color of «10» instead. 
Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

Almost there. Try to define your own syntax group

```
syn match MyComment +\<CONST\>+
hi MyComment term=bold ctermfg=Red guifg=#80a0ff gui=bold
```

- [`:h syn-define`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-define)

Answer (score 0):

#### Augmenting the default syntax

Vim's highlighting consists of two steps:

1. Defining a *syntax element* to parse
2. Assigning colors / linking a *highlight group* to that syntax element

```
syn keyword cMyConst CONST
hi cMyConst term=bold ctermfg=Red guifg=#80a0ff gui=bold
```

If this is for the C language (`:setlocal filetype?` is `c`), you can make that permanent for all C source code files by putting those lines into `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`.

#### One-time highlighting

You can define custom highlightings for a single *window* via `:match` or `:call matchadd(...)`. As you want a custom color, that highlight group needs to be defined, too:

```
:hi MyConst term=bold ctermfg=Red guifg=#80a0ff gui=bold
:match MyConst /\<CONST\>/
```

This won't persist, but is good for ad-hoc highlightings. If you want more of these or a more comfortable way, have a look at my [Mark plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666).